# Internal working of Integer class

Tags: java, bytecode

I wanted to know some internal working of `Integer` class.

For example we can write:

```
Integer num = 9;
```

I wanted to know how an `Integer`class is created in this case, as we have not created
any `Object`. How does it works internally?

Comment: One word: auto-boxing. Here's the JLS for boxing: [JLS §5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7), and unboxing: [JLS §5.1.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is called autoboxing, a feature introduced in Java 5. The Java compiler transforms your statement into:

```
Integer num = Integer.valueOf(9);
```

You can read more about autoboxing here:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 1):

This concept is called auto-boxing. The compiler will change your code to

```
Integer num = Integer.valueOf(9);
```

and continue compiling from there...